# How to send multiple vars via POST as2

Tags: flash, post, combobox, actionscript-2

I hope there are still old school Flash developers here hehe

So I have a simple Flash movie with 2 dropdowns, 1st for school programs and 2nd for state.

**I want to concatenate the program and state to a url like below:**
http://operationmilitaryed.com/search.php?state=AL&interest=Bachelor%27s

**My problem is that I get a URL like this:**

http://operationmilitaryed.com/search.php?changeListener=%5Bobject+Object%5D&the_path=http%3A%2F%2Foperationmilitaryed%2Ecom%2Fsearch%2Ephp&program=Criminal+Justice&us_state=&onLoad=%5Btype+Function%5D

There is too much extra information added to the URL.

**Here is the path to my Flash files** (I would have linked to the test page, but for some reason the dropdowns are not working right in my browsers, possibly different bug)
http://leongaban.com/_stack/flash/as2/combobox/source.zip

---

**Below is my current Flash AS2 code:**

```
import com.mosesSupposes.fuse.*;
ZigoEngine.simpleSetup(Shortcuts,PennerEasing);

Stage.scaleMode = "noScale";
Stage.align = "TL";

var changeListener:Object = new Object;
var changeListener2:Object = new Object; 

var program:String = "";
var us_state:String = "";

attachMovie("comboBox", "combo1", 1);
combo1._x = 6;
combo1._y = 6;

attachMovie("comboBox", "combo3", 3);
combo3._x = 150;
combo3._y = 6;

onLoad = function()
{
combo1.initComboBox("xml/combo2.xml");
combo1.addEventListener("changed",changeListener);

combo3.initComboBox("xml/combo3.xml");
combo3.addEventListener("changed",changeListener2);

changeListener.changed = function(evtObj) 
{
    dataText1.text = evtObj.data;
    program = evtObj.data;
    trace("evtObj.data = "+evtObj.data);
}

changeListener2.changed = function(evtObj) 
{
    dataText2.text = evtObj.data;
    us_state = evtObj.data;
    trace("evtObj.data = "+evtObj.data);
}
}

btn_submit.onRelease = function() {
    var A = program;
    var B = us_state;
    getURL("http://operationmilitaryed.com/search.php", "_blank", "POST");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need send data to script:

```
myVars = new LoadVars();
myVars.interest = program;
myVars.state = us_state;
myVars.send("http://operationmilitaryed.com/search.php", "POST");
```

Also you can use .send, .load, .sendAndLoad

Reference: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00001161.html

If you just want to open URL with php at the end, use concatenate:

```
myUrl = "http://operationmilitaryed.com/search.php?interest=" + program + "&state=" + us_state;
getURL(myUrl, "_blank");
```

Also you can make that crazy thing:

```
this.createEmptyMovieClip("dataMC", this.getNextHighestDepth());
dataMC.interest = program;
dataMC.state = us_state;
dataMC.getURL("http://operationmilitaryed.com/search.php", "_blank", "POST");
```

Comment: I got this to work! Now my problem is the comboboxes don't show up in the browser window :( must be different bug... thanks

Comment: I see 2 combos... Opening your sources in CS5.5, compiling and all ok

Comment: Oh the problem is when I view it in the browser online, don't see the combos in Chrome. And on Firefox the variables do not attach to the string :(

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong but it seems as though the four variables you define towards the top path, program, state and change listener are causing most of the additional post information? And it seems as though the way you use those variables that they could be defined within the functions that they are used, which I believe would eliminate the problem.
let me know

Comment: Did not think so, cleaned up my code btw, still having issues... this is like so ancient to me now :(

Comment: Trying and AS3 way around this problem now, will probably end up deleting this question